# How to make bot send Direct Message To Someone that the bot don't have it in mutal servers and have his id

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to know the code that I can get the user that the bot isn't in his mutual servers and I have his id I want the bot to send him Direct Message what is the code?

I didn't try anything I'm a noob at this in learning

Comment: This isn't possible. While you can retrieve the user, you won't be able to send them a message unless the bot shares a server with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Client.fetchUser()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=fetchUser) method.

Example 1:

```js
let ID = '123456789012345678';

client.fetchUser(ID)
  .then(user => user.send('hello'))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Example 2 *(must be within an async function)*:

```js
let ID = '123456789012345678';

try {
  let user = await client.fetchUser(ID);
  await user.send('hello');
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: A bot cannot DM a user if it does not share a mutual guild with that user